# Who or what are 'mugharribun'?

Tags: hadith-interpretation, jinn, human-body

> Narrated Aisha, Ummul Mu'minin:
>
> The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said to me:
>  *Have the mugharribun been seen
> (or some other word) among you?* 
> I asked: What do the mugharribun mean?
> He replied: **They are those in whom is a strain of the Jinn.** 
>  [Sunan
> Abi Dawud 5107](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/43/335)

What did the Prophet Muhammed mean by a 'strain' of the jinn?

Is it physically or in behavior? If physically, how would inter-species copulation be possible?

Comment: Note that the hadith is weak and the topic is discussed among scholars. And the interpretations I found don't answer this clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the hadith the Prophet ﷺ explained the meaning of '**mugharribun**' as follows:

> الذين يشترك فيهم الجن
>
> Those in whom the Jinn have a share

This can be a paraphrasing of the Quranic verse regarding a form of the attack of the devils against the people:

> وشاركهم في الأموال والأولاد
>
> Become a partner in their wealth and their children
>
> <sup>— [Quran 17:64](https://quran.com/17/64?translations=20)</sup>

The following are some of the explanations given by the scholars regarding who is meant:

- Those who when they were conceived, their parents did not perform remembrance of Allah (see [Bukhari 5165](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5165)), so Satan joined them in their intercourse and corrupted the child.
- Those who were born due to Zina (fornication\adultery). That is because Satan tempted the parents to do that.
- Those who are born from the coitus between and the sexual fluids of a human and a jinn. i.e. they are half human and half jinn.
- Those fortunetellers who have companions among the Jinn who bring them information.
- Those who are possessed by Jinn.
- Those who are misguided by the devils into Kufr and sins.

---

**Ref:**

> قيل: أي عن ذكر الله تعالى عند الوقاع حتى شارك فيهم الشيطان، وقيل: أراد أمر الشيطان بالزنا فجاء أولادهم عن غير الشدة، ويحتمل أن يراد من كان له قرين يلقي إليه الأخبار الكهانة وقيل المغرب من الإنسان من خلق من ماء الإنسان والجن
>
> <sup>—  [Fath al-Wadood](https://shamela.ws/book/20591/2823#p1) also see [Sharah Mishkat](https://shamela.ws/book/145212/4351#p1)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

If I am correct, it is when a human and a Jinn have a child together.

Narrated Ayesha:
The Apostle of Allah said to me: "Have the mugharribun been seen among you?" I asked: "What do the mugharribun mean?" He replied: "They are those in whom is a strain of the Jinn."

Comment: This answer is simply restating the hadeeth in the question. It seems like it is only adding a guess.

Answer (score -2):

I think its just a particular tribe of Jinn. Different tribes can also have different types of feeding, or mechanism of doing evil or good. But in this case I would say evil or feed. The feeding is done when you have unprotected intercourse or masturbation. Why do you think you must control yourselves and not to approach your wives with lust? Jinn are energies (smokeless fire = plasma, which everywhere). Their energies are everywhere. Praying, zikr, contemplation, repenting are forms of purifying yourself to increase your energy, your ruhh. It is to become pure and clean, clean from this world and its impurities that latch on you. You must do everything with a clear consciouness and not to be manipulated by evil jinns.

This particular tribe of jinn feeds or enters you during copulation/ejaculation.